# Is it possible to implement a function for many specific types without direct repetition?

Tags: generics, rust

There is a similar question about implementing the same trait on many different types that was asked 6 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212998/how-to-implement-a-trait-in-the-same-way-for-many-types-without-repetition). I am also wondering if there are any updates on that.

For my question, suppose that

```
struct Foo { data: SomeType }

fn convert(num: u128) -> SomeType {
    //This function only works on u128 and processes it into some data in a unique way
    todo!();
}

//Now we want to create the Foo wrapper using the convert function
impl<T: Into<u128>> From<T> for Foo {
    fn from(other: T) -> Self {
        Foo{ data: convert(other.into()) }
    }
}
```

This is probably the default way to do it. But what if I want to blacklist specific types even if they implement `Into<u128>`, or whitelist only some types?

Suppose now we want to work with `i128`, for which `<u128 as From<i128>>` doesn't exist, but it can still be sensibly converted into an `u128` using an `as` cast. The implementation below is meant to work with all primitive interger types since all of them can be converted into `u128` using `as`.

```
//Now there is a problem!
impl<T> From<T> for Foo {
    fn from(other: T) -> Foo {
        Foo {data: convert(other as u128)}
    }
}
```

The problem occurs because of the conflict between our implementation and the blanket implemention of `From<T> for T` in `std`. We did not specify any trait bounds.

In this case, one can simply use the helpful traits provided in the `num` or `num_traits` crates to bound `T` to primitive integers.
Without using such trait bounds, is there a macro that can produce a bunch of implementations for a list of different types where the syntactic body is identical?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. It sounds like you solved your specific problem with `num` traits. But now you're asking about a macro to solve some unspecified generalisation of the problem?

Comment: If you want 12 implementations that rely on different implementations of some other traits, but otherwise have identical syntactic bodies, then this is a very simple use case for a macro. But you need to clarify the question to be more concrete about what you are looking for.

Comment: @PeterHall Sorry if I was unclear. I’m asking if there’s a way to whitelist a whole bunch of specific types at once that may not have common traits but can be handled by the same implementation at once, much like the example above.

Comment: @PeterHall is the current edit clear enough? i’m fairly new to rust so i’m not very sure how to express what i’m saying clearly.

Comment: Yes, the way is called macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a macro:

```
macro_rules from_foo {
    // The first part is a pattern that describes the expected input:
    //  - `$(...),*` means repeat the contents 0 or more times, with comma separator
    //  - `$t: ty` introduces a variable called `$t` which is a type
    //  - `$(,)?` is just to allow an optional trailing comma
    ($($t: ty),* $(,)?) => {
        // In the output, anything inside the `$(...)*` gets repeated for every `$t` in the input
        $(
            impl From<$t> for Foo {
                fn from(other: $t) -> Foo {
                    Foo { data: convert(other as u128) }
                }
            }
        )*
    }
}

from_foo!(u128, i128, u64, i64, u32, i32);
```

Note that these implementations will still conflict with your implementation for `T: Into<u128>`, so you will need to implement `Foo` for non-confirming types separately, or add a different macro if there are a few that have the same implementation.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose the only way that these types of implementations will become easier is if Rust implements specialisations.